# How Can I Get Apps To Use Nautilus Instead Of Dolphin

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, default-programs, dolphin

I have `kde-desktop` installed on my Gnome based Ubuntu 20.04x system because I use and depend on many of the apps that are only available from the kde package and as a result Dolphin is included in my system.

Firefox and Chrome both use Dolphin instead of Nautilus (Files) but I don't use Dolphin and I don't want to use different file managers on the same desktop. Nautilus is my standard 'finder'.

There is no configurable in Settings -> Default Applications and I tried removing Dolphin from `inode/directory` in `mimeinfo.cache` with no impact.

How do I configure Ubuntu to have all apps use Nautilus (files) as the default file manager?

Comment: File picker and file manager are generally two different things.

Comment: I agree, in this case I am talking about file managers and not pickers. Eg, in Firefox, when opening download in folder, it opens Dolphin when I want it to open Nautilus.

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats the file picker/chooser.

Comment: Firefox -> Downloads -> Open Containing folder -> This launches Dolphin window (has Help -> About Dolphin version 19.12.3. Now conversely, if I hit Alt-O, I get a Nautilus based File picker/chooser dialog.